# Ubuntu 16.04 - Firefox 61.0.1 not resolving zeroconf hosts

Tags: 16.04, firefox, zeroconf

I've installed Firefox 61.0.1 for provided by "Ubuntu Software". Try to access to some zeroconf hosts (machine.local). It's not working. The zeroconf hosts resolving works globally (Chromium, commands like ping) but not in Firefox.

I'm typing the full address with protocol : http://machine.local
Firefox replaces the address http://www.machine.local like if he failed to resolve it (what it does)

The same call on Firefox on Mac (same version 61.0.1) works.

I tried to disable the DNS cache but it doesn't help.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thank you,

Marc

Answer (score 1):

I removed the Firefox installed via "Ubuntu Software" (seems to be installed via snap) and installed it again with apt.

It works.